# Fourier transform $|x|$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Can anyone explain to me why $\mathrm{Fourier}(|x|)=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}/w^2$, for $|x|\leq1$?

Doing the integral as per definition, I found it to be like this:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28|x|*e^%28-i*w*x%29%2Cx%3D-1..1%29%3B

(Copy and paste the link)

Comment: Could you please supply some more context?  I have absolutely no idea what you mean by $w$.  Further, If I guess what you have in mind, then I don't think you are correct.  Moreover, I think you are mixing up the Fourier transform with the FFT algorithm - they are two very distinct things.

Comment: I am talking about the fourier transform, sorry for the typo.

And also, I am using the "Fourier transform unitary, angular frequency". You can find its definition here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

Comment: If you're going to use WolframAlpha, the really use it! http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier+series+abs%28x%29  Unfortunately, I don't believe there's a way to specify the interval, but you should be able to rescale your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get

$$\int_{-1}^1 dx \: |x| e^{i k x} = 2 \frac{\sin{k}}{k} - 2 \frac{1-\cos{k}}{k^2}$$

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be $-ikx$ ?

Comment: There are many ways to define a FT.  In this case, though, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Regardless of the sign, I find your result completely correct and equal to mine. Then why does wolframalpha say it's equivalent to $-sqrt(2/pi)/w^2$ ? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier%28|x|%29+%2C+|x|%3C%3D1

Comment: 1) I made no typo.  I define a FT as $$\hat{f}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: f(x) \, e^{i k x}$$ 2) WA is saying that because it completely ignored your request to limit the range of $x$ in the integration interval to $[-1,1]$.  (Erase the "$|x| \le 1$" and see for yourself.)

Comment: Well: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier%28|x|%29 , same result, but I guess you're right. Thanks for reassuring me :)

Comment: Fine.  The point is to use a definition consistently and stick with it throughout.  I am stubborn about how I define the FT here because I am at ease with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can write $\frac{d}{dx}\vert{x}\vert=2\theta(x)-1$ where $\theta(x)$ is Heaviside step function. Now you take Fourier transform of this function and get $$\mathscr{F}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\vert{x}\vert\right)=\mathscr{F}\left(2\theta(x)-1\right)=i\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}}{k}$$
Now, following theorem of differentiating original function, you can write $$-ik\mathscr{F}\vert{x}\vert=\mathscr{F}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\vert{x}\vert\right)$$
Hence $$\mathscr{F}\vert{x}\vert=\mathscr{F}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\vert{x}\vert\right)\frac{-1}{ik}=-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}}{k^2}$$ Q.E.D.

As for why it's not what you wanted to get is because for $\vert{x}\vert\le1$ you have Fourier series expansion, not integral Fourier transform. In this case you'll have what is given in another answer.

Comment: I disagree with that last statement.  He would have a Fourier series if his function were periodic; it is not.

Comment: @Ron Gordon: What he really tries to do is taking integral with $x\in [-1,1]$. But this is nothing than a Fourier series coefficient. And, if you use this coefficient and try to extrapolate the function beyond that domain, it'll automatically become periodic because its spectrum is discrete.

Comment: It may work out to something that has the same functional form, but it is emphatically not a Fourier Series.  The FT is defined over $(-\infty,\infty)$, while the series is defined on some finite interval.  To "extrapolate", you have to assume periodicity.  But this is hardly the case, i.e., an isolated slit vs a set of periodic slits that form a diffraction pattern.

Comment: Well, find the Fourier series coefficient for original function periodically extended to $x\in [-n,n], n\in\mathbb{N}$. You'll find that it'll coincide with the series for $x\in [-1,1]$.This is just a property of Fourier series that it periodically extends the function over whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You are misunderstanding Ron's point. Ron is talking of the Fourier transform of the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \lvert x\rvert &, \lvert x\rvert \leqslant 1 \\ 0 &, \lvert x\rvert > 1. \end{cases}$$ You can write that as $\lvert x\rvert\cdot \theta(1-x^2)$ if you prefer. That's an entirely different beast than the Fourier series of the periodically extended function.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, so he just extends it in a different way, I see. Thanks for clarification.